# Speed up MySQL Query with join

Tags: mysql

I'm having a little performance issue and I think it may be solved with a better query.

The MySQL table has right now 33,000 entries with following scheme:
ID - kompID (foreign key) - time (Timestamp) - amountIO - amountNIO - status0 - .... - status8

Every few seconds a new Report like the above is inserted and they are deleted when older than 5 days.

For monitoring purposes I need to have the newest entry for every kompID. This for I found the idea with a join here on Stackoverflow:

```
SELECT 
     r1.kompID As ID, 
     (SELECT Name 
         FROM Komponenten 
         WHERE Komponenten.KompID = ID) 
         AS Name,
     r1.time, 
     r1.status0, 
     ...
     FROM Reports r1 
     LEFT JOIN Reports r2 
        ON (r1.kompID = r2.kompID AND r1.RepID < r2.RepID)
     WHERE r2.RepID IS NULL;
```

It works, but with a full database the query needs 150 seconds (on 1 vCore). I could increase the cores, but I'd like to understand what may be done better.

The Output looks like:

```
ID  Name    time                 status0    ....

1   470-U1  2015-08-24 14:00:30     2   ...

2   420-C   2015-08-24 14:00:33     0   ...
```

If there isn't any faster query, i could also first select all ComponentIDs and fire a new query for each selecting the newest entry.

So thanks in advance for your help.

EDIT:
The SQL Structure

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.0.10deb1
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: localhost
-- Erstellungszeit: 24. Aug 2015 um 16:19
-- Server Version: 5.5.44-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
-- PHP-Version: 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.11

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Datenbank: `AMS`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Tabellenstruktur für Tabelle `Reports`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Reports` (
  `RepID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `kompID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `AnzahlIO` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `AnzahlNIO` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `status0` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `status1` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `status2` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `status3` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `status4` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `status5` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `status6` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `status7` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`RepID`),
  KEY `FK_KomponentID` (`kompID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=53447 ;

--
-- Constraints der exportierten Tabellen
--

--
-- Constraints der Tabelle `Reports`
--
ALTER TABLE `Reports`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_KomponentID` FOREIGN KEY (`kompID`) REFERENCES `Komponenten` (`KompID`);

DELIMITER $$
--
-- Ereignisse
--
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` EVENT `AutoDeleteOldReports` ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY STARTS '2015-08-10 10:46:57' ON COMPLETION PRESERVE ENABLE COMMENT 'Reports > 5Tage löschen' DO DELETE LOW_PRIORITY FROM AMS.Reports WHERE time < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 DAY)$$

DELIMITER ;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Fiddle link is here:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9ed73 (I hope it works like that)

Explain statement:
`id     select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra

1   PRIMARY     r1  ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    34560

1   PRIMARY     r2  ref     PRIMARY,FK_KomponentID  FK_KomponentID  4   AMS.r1.kompID   16969   Using where; Using index; Not exists
2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  Komponenten     eq_ref  PRIMARY     PRIMARY     4   func    1`

Comment: Give proper indexes to the table.

Comment: Post your create table output for your tables and an EXPLAIN output, some example data on sqlfiddle.com would also be nice.

Comment: share table wise structure with key details...

Comment: An uncorellated subquery will immeasurably faster. (well, measurably faster, anyway)

Comment: I added the SQL Statements and an link to sqlfiddle, output from EXPLAIN: `id  select_type  table  type  possible_keys  key  key_len  ref  rows  Extra  
1  PRIMARY  r1  ALL  NULL NULL NULL NULL 34560  
1  PRIMARY  r2  ref  PRIMARY,FK_KomponentID  FK_KomponentID  4  AMS.r1.kompID  16969  Using where; Using index; Not exists
2  DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  Komponenten  eq_ref  PRIMARY  PRIMARY  4  func  1  `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this query you have the newest entry for every kompID :

```
select * from Reports r0 where r0.kompID in (
select r1.kompID from (
select r1.kompID, max(time)
from Reports r1
group by r1.kompID ) );
```

The "query-core" is obviously the following:

```
select r1.kompID, max(time)
    from Reports r1
    group by r1.kompID
```

That simply group by kompID and show you, for every different kompID, the one with max date.

Hope I helped you!

Comment: With your query core, I get the newest date, but when i select the RepID (primary key for this table), it is the oldest for each kompID...      `SELECT * FROM Reports r2 where r2.repID in
(
    
     SELECT r0.repID FROM
  (
         SELECT r0.RepID, r0.kompID, 
         max(time)
   from Reports r0 
         GROUP BY r0.kompID
     ) AS r0
)` is the query i tried (oriented on your example)

Comment: try:select * from Reports where repID in (  select repID from ( select r1.kompID,r2.repID, max(time)
    from Reports r1
    group by r1.kompID,r2.repID ) );

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I just noticed the solution is quite easy:

```
SELECT 
(SELECT Name AS Name FROM Komponenten k1 WHERE k1.KompID = r0.kompID), 
time, 
AnzahlIO, 
AnzahlNIO, 
status0 
FROM 
(SELECT * FROM Reports ORDER BY RepID DESC) r0 
GROUP BY kompID
```

So simply select with reversed repID (Primary Key with auto increment), then Select this and group by kompID.
Like this we have a runtime of 0.001 Seconds.

Thanks a lot for your input!